# Find primary key in star schema table

Tags: sql, database

I have encountered a situation while developing a star schema. I have a table like this

| Name | Email |
| --- | --- |
| amy | amy@gmail.com |
| jess | amy@gmail.com |

I want to find the key column as foreign key for Fact table as you can see there is a duplication of records if look individually but unique if consider both column as a key column
Your help will be highly regarded

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming from your question that the table is a dimension? If that is the case then it should have a surrogate key as its PK (as every dimension table should) and you use this to join to fact tables.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this suggestion. Yes, I have a surrogate key with this dimension table. But how can I join this surrogate key with fact table as the fact table doesn't have this surrogate key as common. Also if I join the two tables anyhow then because of duplication in records the wrong output is expected. There are some names in in dimension table using the same email. I want to find a way that I can populate the fact table without duplication to get the correct results. Thanks

Comment: Your source data must include a business key or primary key that allows you to uniquely identify any record. You would bring this in with your fact data from the source system and use it to look up your dimension record and find the correct surrogate key. However, based on the data you provided and what you said in your initial question, I suspect that your data model is fundamentally broken (either in your source system or in your data warehouse) and you don't have the data to allow these lookups to function. If that is the case the only solution is to fix your data model